# jquery to retrieve a top level xml node

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have tried to retrieve the top level 'label' attribute from the following xml using jquery, and having parsed it into a DOM object with no luck. Any suggestions on how I can do this ? I've tried using children(),parent() functions with no luck - I get either no result, or end up having all instances of the label tags passed back to me.

jquery:

```
xml = $.parseXML(xmlString);
$xml = $(xml);
```

I traverse fields via `$($xml).find('fields').each(function(){` etc...
but cannot get that top level `label` data!

```
<customobject>
    <label>want this content</label>
    <fields>
        <label>foo</label>
        <attr1></attr1>
        <attr2></attr2>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <label>foo2</label>
        <attr1></attr1>
        <attr2></attr2>
    </fields>
</customobject>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for `label` which is a child of `customobject` like below. Just using `find('label')` will return contents from all the `label` elements

```js
var xmlString = '<customobject><label>want this content</label><fields><label>foo</label><attr1></attr1><attr2></attr2></fields><fields><label>foo2</label><attr1></attr1><attr2></attr2></fields></customobject>';
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlString);
var $xml = $(xml);

alert($xml.find('customobject > label').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lol - thank you. Very succinct and simple, as I had feared it would be :P

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
    var xml = "<customobject>"+
              "<label>want this content</label>"+
                "<fields>"+
                    "<label>foo</label>"+
                    "<attr1></attr1>"+
                    "<attr2></attr2>"+
                "</fields>"+
                "<fields>"+
                    "<label>foo2</label>"+
                    "<attr1></attr1>"+
                    "<attr2></attr2>"+
                "</fields>"+
            "</customobject>";

  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $firstLabelbject = $xml.find( "customobject label")[0].innerHTML; // Will select first label
  console.log($firstLabelbject);
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/1m1yg9df/2/)